# tkinter: Button Command Not Working After Assigning Image

Tags: python, image, function, tkinter, button

I created a tkinter app which renders classes in separate files into a `main.py` file, the following is code from one such class file:

```
   ButtonSpacer = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)

   def A1Trigger():
        print("Pad A1 Triggered")

   A1 = Button(
      self,
      command=A1Trigger,
      image=ButtonSpacer,
      compound="c",
      text="A1",
      height=90,
      width=90,
      fg="white",
      bg="#717271"
    ).pack(pady=3)
```

I created `ButtonSpacer` so my `A1` button could look even, but after assigning the image to the button the function stopped running onclick. If anyone knows what's wrong please help me out; I'm trying to get the function to run onclick.

Comment: Are you sure this is the code? You'd get the behavior you descrive if you had `command=A1Trigger()` with `()` after it. Adding the image won't cause the button to run immediately.

Comment: @Barmar you're right, my mistake. But now it just doesn't do anything

Comment: You're setting `A1` to `None`, not the button, because `.pack()` doesn't return the button.

Comment: Look like the code is inside a class function, it may be caused by that the image is garbage collected. Try changing `ButtonSpacer` to instance variable `self.ButtonSpacer` instead.

Answer (score 0):

> Button Command Not Working After Assigning Image

When you use this `ButtonSpacer = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)`. This is what you're seeing.

[image]

If you remove parameter `width` and `height` in `PhotoImage` widget. This is what you're seeing.

[image]

code:

```
ButtonSpacer = PhotoImage(file='p1.png')
```